# Google Analytics cookie where one not aught to be

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I was troubleshooting a website I'm working on and I happen to notice one strange thing, a cookie was set for the domain I was working on.  This is odd because I had not even activated session handling, or anything even remotely dependent on cookies at this point.

However, when I looked into it further I discovered that it was a standard Google Analytics cookie named _ga.  The weird part, I have never setup anything with Google at all for analytics at this point either in the project, the library isn't imported into any HTML, the script is never called on, or anything else for that matter.

So does anyone have any idea why such a site would be setting a _ga cookie? The cookie value format looks fairly standard, so i guess I could take the userID in it and take that to Google for more info?

Answer (score 0):

No way to tell why a website would set randomly cookies, but given that name and content are fairly specific to GA my guess would be that some previous project on the same domain added the cookie (GA cookies are very long lived), or that you are working on a subdomain and a project at the top level is setting the cookie (which is then applied also to the subdomain).

If you include third party widgets in your project you might want to check them for GA code (most annoyingly many widget vendors and template providers include tracking code in their products).

But to your question about the id - no, it is very improbable that Google will get you useful information. The clientId (userId is something different in Google lingo) is created randomly per browser (or device), it will not give you any information on the account it was generated by.